# Writing a python script to scatter plot x and y coordinates from a list of user input

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

Im absolutely flabbergasted by my incompetence at the moment. Anyone got a simple frame that I can follow/build upon?

```
(
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Velkommen til GeoGebra sin søtere lillesøster ") 
x = input("Skriv inn x-koordinatene m/ kun mellomrom: ")
x_navn = input("Og hva skal aksen hete? ")
y = input("Skriv inn y-koordinatene m/kun mellomrom: ")
y_navn = input("Og hva skal aksen hete? ")
tittel =input("Hva er tittelen på din nye graf? ")
x_verdier = x.split()
y_verdier = y.split()

 
plt.title(tittel) 
plt.xlabel(x_navn)
plt.ylabel(y_navn)
plt.plot(x_verdier,y_verdier, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

)

This is one of my attempts. Struggling with even defining how to convert user input of numbers into any usable list, or array for that matter. In this attempt I tried the .split(), with instructions to leave a space between each x/y-value

Comment: Why do you have `()` around all the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space-separated input is treated as a string, so after you call `split`, every number is still formatted as a string. Try:

```py
x_verdier = x.split()
x_verdier = [float(xv) for xv in x_verdier]
```